# C++ Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. An exception was thrown: read access violation

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Подскажите пожалуйста при попытке вывода двумерного массива, останавливается на строчке вывода элементов и выводит сообщение:"Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.matr было 0x1110112."
The program stops at the output of the array.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int input(int n, int m, double* array1);
int input(int n, int m, char* array2);
int output(int n, int m, double** matr);
int output(int n, int m, char** matr);

int main(
)
{
    int n, m;
    bool a;
    double** matr1 = 0;
    char** matr2 = 0;
    double* array1 = 0;
    char* array2 = 0;
    cout << "Press 0 to enter numeric data or 1 to enter string data." << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter the number of rows and columns" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> m;
    if (a == 0)
    {

        input(n, m, array1);
        output(n, m, matr1);
    }
    else
    {
        input(n, m, array2);
        output(n, m, matr2);
    }
    return 0;
}

int input(int n, int m, double* array1)
{
    double** matr = new double*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        matr[i] = new double[m];
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<m; j++)
        {
            cout << "VVedite [" << i << "][" << j << "] element: "; cin >> matr[i][j];
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
int input(int n, int m, char* array2)
{
    char** matr = new char*[n];
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    matr[i] = new char[m];

for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<m; j++)
    {
        cout << "VVedite [" << i << "][" << j << "] element: "; cin >> matr[i][j];
    }
}
return 0;
}
int output(int n, int m, double** matr)
{
cout << "Sformirovannaya matrica: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<m; j++)
    {
        printf("matrix[%d %d] = %d,%d\n", i, j, matr[i][j]);

    }
    cout << endl;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
    int output(int n, int m, char** matr)
{
    cout << "Sformirovannaya matrica: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<m; j++)
    {
        cout << matr[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Все Вам правильно говорят... Подумайте, что Вы делаете. В функции `input()` Вы выделяете место и заполняете матрицу `matr` (ну, это массив указателей, но суть не в этом). После этого, Вы этот (эти) выделенный кусок памяти просто "забываете" по выходе из этой функции - Вы никаким образом не передаете во внешнюю среду этот указатель. Получаете утечку памяти в чистом виде. А в следующей функции `output()` Вы думаете, что обращаетесь к этому массиву, но Вы обращаетесь к указателю, заданному в `main()` как 0... Т.е. Проблема в том, что Вы память выделили, но не сообщили об этом в `output()`.

Comment: Очевидные решения проблемы: 1) очень грубый - объявить Вашу `matr` как глобальную переменную и убрать все другие ее объявления (в функции `input()`) и не передавать как параметр. Но лучше так не делать. 2) лучше - выделять память под `matr` в функции `main()`, а для заполнения передавать этот указатель и в `input()` и в `output()`. И не забудьте потом освободить память (для порядка). 3) Раз C++, то еще лучше использовать что-то из стандартных типов, например `vector`. 4) Если у Вас это не учебное задание, то можно использовать специализированную библиотеку для матриц :-) (например, armadillo).

Comment: И еще неприятность: в функции `output()`, где `double **matr`, что Вы выводите? `printf("matrix[%d %d] = %d,%d\n", i, j, matr[i][j]);` У Вас только 3 переменных, а в форматной строке - 4. У Вас только 2 целых и одно `double`, а Вы все (четыре!) пытаетесь вывести как целые. И зачем Вы мешаете в одну кучу `printf()` и `cout`? Лучше остановитесь на чем-то одном (а раз это С++, то `cout`, наверное).

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Помогли.